# Font on mobile Website

Tags: html, css, mobile

I try to add a font in a mobile website with CSS like this:

CSS file:

```
@font-face { font-family: Aapex; font-weight: bold; src: url('../fonts/Aapex.ttf');}
#header_txt{
        font-family: Aapex;
        font-size: 48px;
        color: #fff;
}
```

It works perfectly on a computer browser, but not on a mobile..
Any idea to fix this?

Comment: What's "mobile"? Every single platform and browser? Blackberry, iOS, Android's Chrome, Dolphin, Firefox?

Comment: Which mobile OS and which browser?

Comment: i tried on android with chrome and IOs with safari

Comment: .ttf is not supported by all browsers. It's depends on browser whether it is supporting ttf format or not.

Comment: Which versions? TTF is supported since Safari 4.2 and since Chrome 32.

Comment: how do i know the version on mobiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/ttf) all *current* versions of all the major mobile browsers support .ttf fonts, however some slightly older mobile devices do not. For these you likely need to add embedded opentype fonts (.eot), Web Open Font Format (.woff) and Scalable Vector graphics (.svg) formats to support everything.

Your font declaration will look something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Aapex';
    src: url('fonts/Aapex.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Aapex.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/Aapex.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/Aapex.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/Aapex.svg#Aapex') format('svg');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for cross browser capability !!!

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'YourFontName';
        src: url('YourFontName.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
        src: url('YourFontName.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
             url('YourFontName.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
             url('YourFontName.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
             url('YourFontName.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
        }
```

And convert your ttf format in to eot,woff and svg..please got to the site http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and convert to these format

Answer (score 1):

use @font-face generator by searching on google